# Trying to write Custom Sample in JMeter for programmatic execution

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to run JMeter programmatically with my own sampler.  I have been able to successfully run it with the HTTPSamplerProxy so I'm pretty sure that the process works.
If I simply replace

```
HTTPSamplerProxy javaSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
```

With

```
CustomJavaSampler javaSampler = new CustomJavaSampler();
```

where CustomJavaSampler is

```
public class CustomJavaSampler extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient implements Serializable, Interruptible{
```

I get

> summary =      0 in     0s = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)

as compared to

> summary =     23 in  23.3s =    1.0/s Avg: 21001 Min: 20993 Max: 21008 Err:    23 (100.00%)

A more complete listing of the code that worked follows:

```
    private StandardJMeterEngine doStandardJMeterSetup() {

    File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "jmeter.properties");

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    return jmeter;
}


private void doJMeterStuff(int concurrentCount, int port, List<String> testData) {
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = doStandardJMeterSetup();

    // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

    // Second HTTP Sampler - open jon's machine
    HTTPSamplerProxy javaSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    System.out.println("The domain is: " + testData.get(0) + " " + testData.get(0).getClass().getName());
    javaSampler.setDomain(testData.get(0));
    javaSampler.setPort(Integer.parseInt(testData.get(1)));
    javaSampler.setPath(testData.get(2));
    javaSampler.setMethod("GET");
    javaSampler.setName("Open implementation at " + port);
    javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    Arguments jargs = javaSampler.getArguments();
    jargs.addArgument(new HTTPArgument(testData.get(3), testData.get(4), testData.get(5), true));
    jargs.getArgument(0).setProperty("HTTPArgument.always_encode", false);

    // Loop Controller
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();

    // Thread Group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(concurrentCount);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(2);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    // Test Plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

    // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(javaSampler);
    // threadGroupHashTree.add(javascriptSampler);


    //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
    // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
    Summariser summer = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
    }

    // Store execution results into a .jtl file
    String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    String logFile = tmpDir + File.separator + "example"+port+".jtl";
    CustomResultCollector logger = new CustomResultCollector(summer);
    logger.setFilename(logFile);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

    String logFile2 = tmpDir + File.separator + "example_results_"+port+".jtl";

    ResultCollector r = new ResultCollector();
    r.setFilename(logFile2);
    SampleSaveConfiguration ssc = new SampleSaveConfiguration();
    ssc.setAsXml(true);
    ssc.setResponseData(true);
    ssc.setResponseHeaders(true);
    r.setSaveConfig(ssc);

    ResultSaver rs = new ResultSaver();
    rs.setEnabled(true);
    rs.setName("Responses");

    javaSampler.addTestElement(rs);

    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], r);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], rs);

    // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
    try {
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + File.separator + "example"+port+".jmx"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Run Test Plan
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomJavaSampler, you are probably already overriding `sample` function, so SampleResult it's supposed to return is what will contain data for the statistics. For example the following will ensure sample result will have a start and end time, and will be set to status "success":

```
@Override
public SampleResult sample(Entry e) 
{    
    SampleResult sampleResult = new SampleResult();
    sampleResult.setSampleLabel( "My label" );
    sampleResult.sampleStart();

    // do something useful

    sampleResult.sampleEnd();
    sampleResult.setSuccessful( true );
    sampleResult.setResponseMessageOK();
    return sampleResult;
}
```

Check [SampleResult reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take another look with this direction and see where I get to.